# Why is Plotly switching order of x axis values

Tags: charts, plotly.js

Why is Plotly.js switching the order of "A1" and "B2" for just the second subseries here?
I'd like the order to be `["A1", "B2", "A1", "B2", "A1", "B2", "A1", "B2"]` as specified in the data for the x axis.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/__proto__/pen/yLXMXXO)

[image]

```json
var data ={
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "bar",          
            "name": "1 day",
            "text": [
                "85%",
                "79%",
                "74%",
                "57%",
                "55%",
                "18%",
                "50%",
                "4%"
            ],
            "x": [
                [
                    "Croissant",
                    "Croissant",
                    "Doughnut: Cinnamon",
                    "Doughnut: Cinnamon",
                    "Doughnut: Glazed",
                    "Doughnut: Glazed",
                    "Bagel: Sesame",
                    "Bagel: Sesame"
                ],
                [
                    "A1 (N=17)",
                    "B2 (N=15)",
                    "A1 (N=18)",
                    "B2 (N=15)",
                    "A1 (N=10)",
                    "B2 (N=11)",
                    "A1 (N=6)",
                    "B2 (N=9)"
                ]
            ],
            "y": [
                0.8470588235294118,
                0.7913333333333333,
                0.7357142857142858,
                0.5746666666666667,
                0.55,
                0.18,
                0.5,
                0.03888888888888889
            ],
            "orientation": "v",
            "textposition": "auto",
            "marker": {
                "color": [
                    "#39C",
                    "#FA0",
                    "#39C",
                    "#FA0",
                    "#39C",
                    "#FA0",
                    "#39C",
                    "#FA0"
                ]
            },
            "hoverinfo": "x+y",
            "hoverformat": "0.0%"
        }
    ],
    "layout": {
        "type": "bar",
        "orientation": "v",
        "barmode": "stack",
        "series": {
            "type": "bar",
            "hoverinfo": "x+y",
            "dataLabels": {
                "color": "",
                "size": "",
                "bold": false
            }
        },
       
        "margin": {
            "l": 80,
            "r": 200,
            "t": 0,
            "b": 95
        },
        "xaxis": {                   
            "type": "multicategory",
            "autorange": true,
        },
        "yaxis": {
            "tickformat": "0.0%",
            "rangemode": "tozero",           
            "type": "linear",           
            "autorange": true
        },
        "colorway": [
            "#DADADA",
            "#4DADC7",
            "#8165A2",
            "#884119"
        ],
        "legendpos": "right",
        "width": 800,
        "height": 420,
        "bargap": 0.2
    }
}

Plotly.newPlot("bar-chart-1", data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is occuring as Plotly is apparently assigning scale positions to unique strings. The second "B2 (N=15)" which is the same as the first "B2 (N=15)".

- "A1 (N=17)" is index 0
- "B2 (N=15)" is index 1,  so that sorts after  "A1 (N=17)" at index 0
- "A1 (N=18)" is index 2,
- "B2 (N=15)" is index 1, so that sorts before "A1 (N=18)" at index 2

One hack is to append some number of unprintable characters `"&#x200b;"` to each label, just enough to make the strings appear unique to Plotly but not the user.

```
 [
     "A1 (N=17)",
     "B2 (N=15)",
     "A1 (N=18)",
     "B2 (N=15)&#x200b",
     "A1 (N=10)",
     "B2 (N=11)",
     "A1 (N=6)",
     "B2 (N=9)"
]
```